# How to read an XPathDocument that has a namespace

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-namespaces

I have the following example XML file:

```
<Top xmlns="abbr:SomeNSValue">
  <Next>
    <Other>SomeValue</Other>
  </Next>
</Top>
```

I load it up and try to read it like this:

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(@".\TestXML.xml", FileMode.Open);
XPathDocument xPathDocument = new XPathDocument(stream);
XPathNavigator navigator = xPathDocument.CreateNavigator();

XmlNamespaceManager ns = null;
if (navigator.NameTable != null)
{
    ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(navigator.NameTable);
    ns.AddNamespace("abbr", "SomeNSValue");
}

XPathNodeIterator iterator = navigator.Select("/Top/Next", ns);
iterator.MoveNext();

Console.WriteLine(iterator.Current.InnerXml);
```

This outputs the Full XML shown above.  Not what I am looking for (I want to select the contents of the "Next" node.

But if I take the `xmlns="abbr:SomeNSValue` out of the XML and try again then I get what I was looking for:

```
<Other>SomeValue</Other>
```

In my real scenario I have the XML fed to me and I would rather not have to modify it to take the Namespace off.

Is there a way I can make this work with the namespace in it?

**Note:** Incase it matters this is the actual namespace that I have in my XML file: `xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v2xml"`

Answer (score 5):

Your namespace declaration is wrong:

```
<Top xmlns:abbr="SomeNSValue">
  <Next>
    <Other>SomeValue</Other>
  </Next>
</Top>
```

When you do this magical change the rest of your code works :)..

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up!  I do not generate the xml (though I will try to get those that do to fix this.)  but it would be nice to know if there is there any way to make this work with out editing the file.

Answer (score 3):

Ancient question but I stumbled upon this from Google trying to figure out something similar.  So here's an answer that might help others coming from Google.

What I've come to find out is you have to specify a namespace prefix in the XPath expression (despite there not being a namespace prefix in the XML file).

```
ns.AddNamespace("foo", "urn:hl7-org:v2xml"); // make up whatever prefix you want here
```

And later:

```
XPathNodeIterator iterator = navigator.Select("/foo:Top/foo:Next", ns);
```